# css width, max-width, height not working

Tags: html, css, responsive

I can't find an answer and I'm truly baffled.

I have honestly spent 2 hours ++ on this researching, trialling and breaking this and I'm stumped... What the hell am I doing wrong...

I have a html page, "index.html" which links to a css sheet called "styles.css".

Every style element I incorporate is fine so far so I know the sheet is linked to correctly.

Within my html page's body tags, I have

```
<div id="bgimg"> <img src="img/EXAMPLE.jpg"> </div>
```

In my style sheet I have

```
#bgimg { width: 100%; }.
```

This doesn't work.

I've tried changing the display type, I've tried changing it to max-width and all sorts of other weird and wonderful things.

I'm not a website builder really (in case you couldn't already tell!!) but I even have another separate site where this works perfectly to resize the image based on the screen size.

I'm not getting any change in the image size what so ever.

Please, somebody either help me or kill me. Either way, I'm done. My head has exploded and I just can't anymore...

Cheers.

Comment: Not to kill you, but when you have put your head back together, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ?

```
#bgimg img { width: 100%; }
```

The `#bgimg` is already width 100% (it's a div), but the img on it is an auto-sized element.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what you are looking for is this:

```
#bgimg > img { width: 100%; }.
```

(the image is inside the container, as a direct child element)

Answer (score 1):

you can apply css either directly on img tag like this :

```
img { width: 100%; }
```

or like this :

```
#bgimg img { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: `img { width: 100%; }` is very hard.. You should never update classic HTML tag value like that.